# Can't display routes properly in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi I have this routes in App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route key="products" path="/products" component={Products}></Route>
        <Route key="preview" path="/products/:id" component={Preview}></Route>
        <Route key="add-product" path="/products/create" component={ProductCreate}></Route>
        <Route key="edit-product" path="/products/:id/edit" component={ProductEdit}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

it displays only /products and / others are not displayed they get Products component displayed and I don't understand why.
For example my product edit looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const ProductEdit = (props) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <p>Product Edit page</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductEdit;
```

and this is the result I get:

[image]

Can't find the problem my self...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must organise paths within Switch such that the prefix paths are at the end.

The issue with the current code is that when you are on path say `/products/:id`, it matches path `/products` too since it is prefix path and hence it only renders Products Component as Switch renders just the first matching Route

The reordered version of your paths will be as follows

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route key="edit-product" path="/products/:id/edit" component={ProductEdit}></Route>
    <Route key="add-product" path="/products/create" component={ProductCreate}></Route>
    <Route key="preview" path="/products/:id" component={Preview}></Route>
    <Route key="products" path="/products" component={Products}></Route>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 1):

`/products/:id` path will match `/products/create` and also `/products/:id/edit` and as you are using `Switch`, once the route matches, no further routes will be rendered.

Reordering `Route` components will solve the problem

```
<Route key="edit-product" path="/products/:id/edit" component={ProductEdit}></Route>
<Route key="add-product" path="/products/create" component={ProductCreate}></Route>
<Route key="preview" path="/products/:id" component={Preview}></Route>
```